# Exporting contents of a TextBox to a Text File Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, web-applications, button, textbox, text-files

I am trying to export the contents of a textbox to a txt file at the press of a button "Export". I am using web application forms in Visual Studio in C#.

I have got the txt file creation part working at the press of a button. But I am unable to export the data from the textbox into the text file.

The textbox's contents are referencing a DataGrid so how can I link the program in C# so that at the press of the button "Export" it transfers the contents fo the textbox into the text file?

So the code below is what I have to create a text file. What would I need to add to this, to do the above?

```
    private void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //DataRowView drv = ((DataRowView)ordersBindingSource.Current);
         //DataRow dr = drv.Row;        

        string path = @"G:\bin\Debug\Test.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hi," + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sw.WriteLine("Order ID: ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please Help!! I am working on a project and stuck at this level of exporting information.

Comment: Do you want to export file on web server folder ? This makes no sense, and if you save file under bin folder that will cause reset of web app

Comment: No not on a web server. I must create a file int the local directory. I just set the path to the project bin/Debug folder.

Comment: you can't write to local directory, for starters your code runs on web server, all you can do is serve that text file and user will decide what to do with this file

Answer (score 2):

Put your textbox in a form
Then set the Export button to be a submit button (also in the form)

On the server, when the post is done, you'll be able to access to the textbox content (`this.Forms` if I'm not wrong, it's a long time I didn't use asp.net)

Once you have the textbox content, you just need to use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"G:\bin\Debug\Test.txt", textBoxContent)
```

Be carefull: Asp.net doesn't have the permissions to write anywhere on the disk, you may need to give permission on a specific directory